# C# Can't change labels and button properties from a dialogbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have my main form and a dialogbox which is called from main. In my main form I have a label and a button that which properties I can't change. I'm using Visual Studio 2015, not sure if there is a bug regarding this. I also made sure my label and button are set to public to modify.

Code: (this is from the dialog box, this has a list box the function is triggered at selectindexchange)

```
else if ((short)lbDiscountTypes.SelectedValue == 2) //Senior
                {
                    frm_Main main = new frm_Main();
                    main.VAT = false;
                    main.labelStatus.Text = "NON-VAT (SENIOR)";
                    main.labelStatus.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.IndianRed;
                    main.labelStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
                    main.btnNonVat.Enabled = false;
                    main.btnNonVat.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SlateGray;
                    main.btnNonVat.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Navy;
                    main.labelVatAmount.Text = 0.00m.ToString();
                    main.Dispose();

                    //INQUIRE DISCOUNT TYPES
                    var Discount = GC.CSHR_DiscountTypes.Where(Filter => Filter.DiscountCode == (short)lbDiscountTypes.SelectedValue);
                    decimal DP = 0.00m;
                    foreach (var item in Discount)
                    {
                        DP = item.DiscountPercentage;
                    }

                    foreach (var item in GC.CSHR_SORepo
                                        .Where(Filter => Filter.Machine == MACHINE
                                            && Filter.SalesOrderNum == SALESORDERNUM
                                            && Filter.First_SRP == Filter.IMFSRP))
                    {
                        item.DiscountAmount = (item.SoldSRP * DP) / 100;
                        item.TotalAmount = (item.Quantity * item.SoldSRP) - item.DiscountAmount;
                        item.VATableSalesOnTotalAmount = (item.Quantity * item.SoldSRP) - item.DiscountAmount;
                        item.VATRate = 0.00m;
                        GC.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    Close();
                }
```

The code below `//INQUIRE DISCOUNT TYPES` works well but not the one on top.
I've used debug mode to check if the lines are not being skipped over and they aren't.

Comment: First- You are creating a new instance of your main form that you don't need (while it is open behind the dialog)  Second- labelStatus and btnNonVat are protected and should be public

Comment: labelStatus and btnNonVat are set to public.  "I also made sure my label and button are set to public to modify."

Comment: And did you are using `frm_Main main = new frm_Main();` and then disposing it!

Comment: Why are you assigning `DP` in a loop like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pay attention to:

- You are creating a new instance of your main form that you don't need (while it is open behind the dialog), so you need to get it not create a new instance
- You are disposing the main form you created. `main.Dispose();`

In fact you are creating a new instance of main form and assigning values to those controls and then dispose it. While and instance of yor main form that you expect to see changes on it, is open and untouched behind your dialog.

To set value of those controls you can do one of these ways:

**Option 1**

Make your labelStatus and btnNonVat public. Open your main form in designer and select labelStatus and btnNonVat and in property grid, set `Modifier` to public. Then write this code:

```
//var main = Application.OpenForms.OfType<frm_Main>().FirstOrDefault();
var main = (frm_Main)Application.OpenForms["frm_Main"];
main.labelStatus.Text = "NON-VAT (SENIOR)";
main.labelStatus.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.IndianRed;
main.labelStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
main.btnNonVat.Enabled = false;
main.btnNonVat.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SlateGray;
main.btnNonVat.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Navy;
main.labelVatAmount.Text = 0.00m.ToString();
```

**Option 2**

Pass an instance of your frm_Main to your dialog and work with it.

**Option 3**

After closing the dialog, use values from dialog and set values of your main form

Comment: They are in public. I have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to create new form using `frm_Main main = new frm_Main();` syntax. All you need to do is get the instance of your current  form.

```
            var _currentMainForm= Application.OpenForms[0];
```

or if you have given name to your form

```
            var _currentMainForm = Application.OpenForms["MainFormName"];
```

Once you get the reference  you can perform all your label updates.

Answer (score 0):

The code on top creates a new form, changes the labels and then disposes the form.
I think you should change the labels of the existing form.

Answer (score 0):

Like in the other answer said you are setting properties of controls into a new Form object and not in the form where you come from.
You should pass the form object into the parameters of the dialog, something like:

```
void myDialog(frm_Main callingForm)
{
   callingForm.Textbox1.Text = "abc";
}
```

And call it from you main form like this

```
...
myDialog(this);
```